# Problem with manifest.js (cannot get from temp)

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

I have problem with my project on React and Sharepoint, after i called **gulp clear**

[image: problem]

my serve.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://thisisprivatesite/sites/trainings-team/_layouts/workbench.aspx",
  "api": {
    "port": 5432,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

also tried **npm install**, deleting my node_modules
my temp folder is empty
[image: temp]

**upd**: i think typescript dosent create **dist** folder
Any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` to restore the original state of the project, then start the project normally.

Comment: Same problem, already tried

Comment: Try to delete node_modules before that

Comment: tried that already, still same

Comment: Does creating a new project from scratch work for you? yo @microsoft/sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the manifest.js really wasn't in the temp directory...nothing was! Looks similar to your screenshot with an empty temp directory. Just had to run:

`gulp bundle`

and it came back! I actually ran:

`npx gulp build && npx gulp bundle && npx gulp trust-dev-cert && npx gulp serve`

Just to be safe :)